# How to refresh listbox that have data source in c#

Tags: c#, listbox, datasource

Hellow,
I start a litle project in windows form c#
thats form build in 2 panels
in one you can add new data to table in db
and in the another panel you can see all table details in listbox by connecting to data source.
My problem is that when I add data to the db the list box doesnt refresh/update.
what is the command to refresh/update data listbox?

and how can I refresh the data listbox every 5min?

tnx

Comment: you need to show the binding / assign then null it out after adding the rebind show some code please.. along with using a timer

Comment: 300 milliseconds (3/10 of a second), not 300 seconds (5 whole dadburned minutes).